# LinqtoSQL -- Mapping Problem: Unable to resolve root for type

Tags: linq-to-sql, poco

We are experimenting with several different persistence layers for our current project.  We are trying for a POCO/PI approach.  One of our candidates is LinqToSql.  I am following the work presented by Vijay Mehta in "Pro LINQ Object Relational Mapping with C# 2008", in which the POCOs and the mapping files are created by hand.

I have the following POCO:

```
namespace CIN.CIN2010.DomainModel.Notifications
{
    public abstract class Notification //: Repository.BaseEntity
    {

        public Notification(int notificationId, OwnerTag owner, DateTime creationDateTime, string message)
        {
            this._notificatonId = notificationId;
            this._owner = owner;
            this._creationDateTime = creationDateTime;
            this._message = message;
        }

        // omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

and I have this for a mapping file:

```
<Database Name="CINFulfillment" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/mapping/2007">
  <Table Name="dbo.tblNotifications" >
      <Type Name="CIN.CIN2010.DomainModel.Notifications.Notification, CIN.CIN2010.DomainModel" InheritanceCode="0" IsInheritanceDefault="true">
        <Column Name="NotificationID" Member="NotificationID" Storage="_NotificationID" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" AutoSync="OnInsert" />
        <Column Name="NotificationTypeID" Member="NotificationTypeID" Storage="_NotificationTypeID" DbType="TinyInt NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="OwnerID" Member="OwnerID" Storage="_OwnerID" DbType="Int NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="OwnerTypeID" Member="OwnerTypeID" Storage="_OwnerTypeID" DbType="TinyInt NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="SubTypeID" Member="SubTypeID" Storage="_SubTypeID" DbType="TinyInt NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="CreationDateTime" Member="CreationDateTime" Storage="_CreationDateTime" DbType="SmallDateTime NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="Message" Member="Message" Storage="_Message" DbType="VarChar(255) NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" />
        <Column Name="RequiresAction" Member="RequiresAction" Storage="_RequiresAction" DbType="Bit NOT NULL" />
        <Column Name="ActionTypeID" Member="ActionTypeID" Storage="_ActionTypeID" DbType="TinyInt" />
        <Column Name="DueDateTime" Member="DueDateTime" Storage="_DueDateTime" DbType="SmallDateTime" />
        <Column Name="CompletedDateTime" Member="CompletedDateTime" Storage="_CompletedDateTime" DbType="SmallDateTime" />
        <Column Name="CompletedStatusID" Member="CompletedStatusID" Storage="_CompletedStatusID" DbType="TinyInt NOT NULL" />
      </Type>
  </Table>
</Database>
```

When I try to load the mappingsource, I end up with an error:

> Failed    CanInstantiateDataContext   CIN.CIN2010.Persistence.L2S.Test    Test method CIN.CIN2010.Persistence.L2S.Test.ContextTests.CanInstantiateDataContext threw exception:  System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Nested' threw an exception. --->  System.InvalidOperationException: Mapping Problem: Unable to resolve root for type 'CIN.CIN2010.DomainModel.Notifications.Notification'..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Remove ", CIN.CIN2010.DomainModel" from Name attribute. Linq to SQL find assembly itself.